# HDMI mirroing issue

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and i'm trying to mirror my screen to a TV using HDMI.
When I connect the cable, nothing happens.
The screen is not in display settings and there are no mirror screen option no where.

output from xandr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  40.03  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.02
```

tried `sudo xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --auto` but no good

The graphics card is `/0/100/1/0 display GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M]` With the Nvidia 390 driver

Comment: Graphics card an drivers version (if you installed)?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia `/0/100/1/0                display        GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M]`
`/0/100/2                  display        HD Graphics 530`
and the Nvidia 390 driver

Comment: Nvidia mentions 418 only: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/145182/en-us . If not available in the 18.04 repositories, add the graphics drivers PPA. And please [edit] the question to add new or requested info, do not use comments.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I've installed it from the Software&Updates desktop application (there are no 418). I've tried to download the driver from nvidia's website and install it but it kept failing with the following error "Unable to determine the version of the kernel sources"

Comment: Do not use the Nvidia binary. As I said before, if not available for your release in the official repos, add the graphics drivers PPA (additional software source.